# is it possible to limit an image library size

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

In sharepoint 2007 
we have an image libraryy which is using around 2GB of space

we need to limit the library to not allow the user to add more images once it is 2.5 GB is that possible in sharePoint and how?

plz help

regards.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: yes cause limiting the size in sharepoint most probably will be through writting a .NET code that checks and block upload of more images, but the question is also asking if it is this way then how, and if there other alternatives then what are they

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not out of the box.
You have to create a class that derives from [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.aspx) and that checks the current size every time an image is added/deleted/updated.

Once the Threshold is reached you can change permissions on the list.

Alternatively, you can do that check in the [ItemAdding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx) method and set `properties.Cancel = true` in case the threshold is reached.

I don't know off hand what the most efficient approach is since checking file sizes of each list item every time a new one is added is going to be expensive:

```
long totalSize = 0;
foreach(SPFile file in list.RootFolder.Files){ 
    totalSize += file.Length; // or TotalLength, see MSDN
}
```

I think I'd just store the current usage in a variable in the [SPList.RootFolder.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.properties.aspx)  and update it in the ItemAdded/ItemUpdated methods of the Item Event Receiver.